# How can I calculate wheel size

Tags: tires, wheels

I am building a little plane for aerodesign purposes.
I am wondering how can I calculate the best size/diameter of wheels for my plane based on its load, speed and other parameters.

Somebody please give me a light.

Comment: Are you talking a model/RC plane? Or are you talking an actual aircraft?

Answer (score 2):

Find a car or trailer that has similar weight to your plane, and get the smallest wheel size that the car has.

Keep in mind, if you need to have a braking system inside the wheel, the wheel needs to be big enough to house that.